# One Single Place to See Cumulative Rewards

Tags: baking, rewards, staking-balance

Where can I go to see a cumulative number of rewards for my particular account? (I understand that rewards are released on a lag.) I can see the rewards for each cycle on tzscan, but short of adding them all up (tedious for soon-to-be-more-than-100) where can I get the total?

Answer (score 3):

If by account you mean baker, then https://bakendorse.com does what you ask for.

The stats page has the cumulative unlocked earnings of your baker and avg. earnings per cycle.

see this example:
https://bakendorse.com/#/bakers/tz1eFXLaCUcKbhXkLBGUGMGNY9tKHjWGG25V/projected_stats

Comment: I use bakendorse.com. The stats are not current. They're three cycles behind. Right now it shows stats for 105 but it should be 108.